# How to play an opening animation when iOS app launches

Tags: iphone, image, animation, launch

I am trying to get the code correct to play an opening animation on my iphone app I created in xcode. I want it to only play when the app launches (like angry birds) not every time I go back to the main page. I have tried several things and nothing seems to be working correctly. Can someone tell me how to correctly do this?

I am using a series of images to create the animation.

I have tried to put the animation code from geeky lemon tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AbdZ-8JBZQ) in the viewDidLoad. This does work and play the animation but every time I go back to the main page the animation plays. I don't want the animation to play when go back to the main page, just when the app starts.

I have also tried to add another view that is the first view when the app launches and have the animation play in viewDidLoad there and then with perform selector go to the main page after the animation is complete (done with the after Delay part). This also works and does play the animation and does not play when I go back to the main screen BUT this is causing some error making the app crash. I have put NSLogs in the viewDidLoad sections so I can see the pages are working and sometimes when I am in the app playing it says that my opening animation viewDidLoad is being called. So I think this has something to do with the crashing. When I take out this view and go directly to the main view it doesn't crash.

I have tried to put it in the app delegate also and I can't get that to work at all.

Please help this is driving me crazy I can't figure out what is going wrong. I know it can work angry birds and others do this very successfully.

If there is a better method?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage3.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage4.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage5.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage6.png"], nil];


    imageView.animationDuration = 0.5;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 3;
    [imageView startAnimating];
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];

    return YES;
}
```

add the animation as a subview for you `self.window`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to include it in the - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application method of your app delegate, this is called only when your app is "launched".

Comment: No. This is called upon every launch which is not what OP wants.

Comment: Kyle Thank you for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also put it in

> -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

I have a view controller and in that I load the view. Call this from there.

If your animation is in a single view you can have that animation running on a separate thread with sleep on the main thread.

> (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
> // Add sub view
>
> [window addSubview:animationController.view];
> // after some time do another thing
> [self performSelector:@selector(firstcontroller)  withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
> [window makeKeyAndVisible];
> }
>
> -(void)firstcontroller{
> [window addSubview:firstControllerAfterLaunch.view];
> }

Comment: I'm sorry I am kind of new and really not sure what you mean. Can you explain a little more? Thanks.

Comment: In your app delegate there is this method that I have posted above. In there you call your view controller. If its an animation in a background thread then you need to have a "sleep"command present in there to make your main thread sleep otherwise your other views will be loaded. If no threads are being used then you can just load your own view controllers

Comment: How can I do this is if I am using only one thread? I don't know how to work with multiple threads.

Comment: If you are not working with multiple threads then you only need to call the view controller that handles the animation.

Comment: Okay... do you know where there is some sample code that I could look at? I have tried coding in the app delegate and it doesnt work right for me. It eiter doesn't work at all or the animation doesnt play.

Answer (score 0):

Put your animation method into the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)opts
```

method. Use a separate view designated for the animation. Add it to the key window of the application and remove it when the animation ends.

Comment: Are you saying to put that in the app delegate? That is what I tried to do but none of my code is working. It either wont play at all or wont actually play the animation (this is with the animation on it's own view). What do you mean by "the key window of the application"?                                                        Is there some sample code that you could point me to, I am fairly new and I am just not being able to figure out how to do this correctly.

Comment: @user1588717 you must have messed up something, I've done this before. And I meant `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the animation code in your viewDidAppear using dispatch_once. That way, you will ensure that the animation will be called just once during the lifetime of the application.

Comment: I am not very familure with dispatch_once. I looked in Apple's documentation and it says "Executes a block object once and only once for the lifetime of an application". That seems like it would only ever play once. I would like it to play every (or most every) time the app is open I just don't want it to play when the user goes back to the main page. Let me know if I misunderstood what Apple's documentation said. Thank you.